# Single LinearLayout vs Single ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

If I have just a single LinearLayout with a few items in it, then what effects will be of replacing it with ConstraintLayout

```
<LinearLayout>
   <TextView>
   <TextView>
   <TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

vs

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <TextView>
   <TextView>
   <TextView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Are there any differences in their efficiencies?

Comment: Do you mean being more efficient in terms of memory consumption or time needed to layout the views? If there just a handful of views, I would probably prefer RelativeLayout (though not being part of your question ;-)), which has always been praised as being efficient. And keep in mind that ConstraintsLayout comes as an additional lib whereas both LinearLayout and RelativeLayout are builtin.

Comment: By efficient I mean time needed to layout the views. Adding a lib is not a concern.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For such a simple layout with no nesting and only 3 children TextView, LinearLayout is the best on conceptual complexity, on performance, on drag and drop user interface of Android Studio, on XML lines, on kB size of the app. Maybe I forgot something, but I would not dare to waste time and mess things with any other layout than the LinearLayout in this case.

Comment: Any official references to this claim?